# Is there a way to create a directly accessible URL to a file stored as varbinary(max) in a mySQL database?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, url, preview

I have a number of different types of files stored in a MySQL database (varbinaryMAX). I am in the process of building a document management system and my final phase is to install some sort of document viewer so that these files can be prievewed.

I have veered away from Google Docs due to the security of the documents. I have [preliminarily] settled with [Viewer.JS](http://viewerjs.org/) as my chosen method of preview as it supports a wide variety of filetypes, and is free. It does however require a directly accessible URL for the file, which I of course dont have as the file is sitting in a coloumn in the DB.

How would I go about generating a URL that can be used to access a/the file in the DB?

Application is ASP.net

Comment: How do you intend to restrict the access to those URL's?

Comment: They will be generated by the platform, using keys, namely the fileID, that has to match another unique key that is generated when the preview is initiated.